# Проверить вхождение маршрута в другой маршрут

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Задача такая, есть общий маршрут, а есть отдельные участки, которые необходимо объезжать, есть ли возможность проверить входят ли отдельные участки в общий маршрут, и если есть то прокладывать маршрут через промежуточные точки.

Comment: Построить маршрут, получить точки и построить по ним линию можно так https://jsfiddle.net/1gubj8a3/ расстояние от точки до линии можно найти как в этом примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/tracks_compare если расстояние близко к нулю, значит маршрут проходит через точку.

Comment: Спасибо, ваши примеры помогли решить задачу.

Comment: @se0ga, подскажите, а как можно перерисовать мультимаршрут, т.е. я нашел, что отрезок входит в основной маршрут, теперь мне необходимо перерисовать основной маршрут в обход этого отрезка, т.е. проложить уже отрисованный маршрут по новым точкам.

Comment: По сути перерисовка маршрута, это прокладывание нового маршрута, так что удалите предыдущий и создайте новый.

Comment: Ладно, я погорячился. Ответ выше имеет право на жизнь, но также вы можете просто перезадавать точки маршрута так: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving

Comment: @se0ga, спасибо за ответы, очень помогли. Не подскажите, а может у яндекса есть готовое решение, которое позволяет при задании определенных точек, строить маршрут в объезд этих точек, а то как вы описали выше сделал, но правда очень медленное решение получается.

Comment: А что за задачу вы решаете, зачем вам объезжать эти точки? Ответ на этот вопрос поможет понять могу ли я что-то предложить.

Comment: Пишу бота для транспортной компании, у них есть участки с плохой дорогой, участки где при определенном тоннаже транспорта, машина просто в гору не заедет и т.д., и для построения маршрута перевозки такие участки необходимо объезжать.

Comment: Напишите сюда: routing@yandex-team.ru Распишите, подробно, что хотите получить.

Comment: Спасибо большое, написал письмо.